# How to make a diagram for DataFrame of names and ages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, graph

I have a 20*2 pandas DataFrame indexed by names and have another column of ages.

How could I sketch a diagram for it which have names in x-axis and in each name be as high as age of that person?

Comment: you can use a barplot

Comment: Use ```matplotlib.pyplot``` module

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on my data :( maybe because my data is indexed by names, or maybe because type(mydata.index) gives pandas.core.indexes.category.CategoricalIndex. how could I do on mydata? @DavideBrex

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve your problem using matplotlib.pyplot module.
Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#create simple dataframe

data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','age'])
names = ["John",'Peter','Sarah']
ages = [33,18,22]
data.name = names
data.age = ages

print(data)

#Output

#    name  age
#0   John   33
#1  Peter   18
#2  Sarah   22
```

Then use matplotlib.pyplot. In this case you want a histogram, so use `plt.bar()`  function

```
plt.figure.figsize = (8,10)
plt.bar(data.name, data.age)
```

Here's a result

[image]

I'll recommend you to search and view some tutorials (there are plenty of them) to understand deeply how this module works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on my data :(  maybe because my data is indexed by names, or maybe because type(mydata.index) gives pandas.core.indexes.category.CategoricalIndex. how could I do on mydata? @Harut Hunanyan

Comment: I don't understand why it shouldn't work. Is it throwing errors? Can you add to your question a little part of your data, to see how it is stored.

Comment: All you need is installing (if you haven't done it already) matplotlib, importing the module, then passing your data to the bar function. Note that this function accepts two main arguments, array-like, for displaying data along x axis, and the same for y axis, so you should pass it separately. Hope this helps.